# with open(), how can I tell if I am at the last line of a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have:

```py
with open(self.corpus_file) as infile:
    for line in infile:
```

How can I tell if `line` is the last line in `infile`?

This is with Python 3.6 if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File objects returned by `open` are iterators in Python, so you can look out for `StopIteration` while doing `next` to consume lines in a `while` loop:

```
with open(self.corpus_file) as f: 
    line = None 
    while True: 
        try: 
            line = next(f) 
        except StopIteration: 
            break
```

Now `line` should contain the last line.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple way:

```py
from itertools import tee

with open(self.corpus_file) as infile:
    infile, check = tee(infile)
    try:
        next(check)
    except StopIteration:
        # file is empty
    for line in infile:
        try:
            next(check)
        except StopIteration:
            # line is the last line
```

Another even simpler way if you don't have to stay in the loop:

```py
with open(self.corpus_file) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        pass

# line is now the last line
```

Comment: Won't the for loop get a `StopIteration` and stop before your `next()` ever does? Seems like you need a `next(check)` before the loop so check is one step ahead.

Comment: Your simpler solution is the perfect solution even you **do** stay in the loop. I mean, on every line, do whatever you want with it, **and** in the end you have the last line available... Don't see why make it more complicated with iterators

Comment: @Tomerikoo I think I could conceive of a complicated situation where it might be necessary.... like perhaps if you both reading and writing to the file at the same time? but most of the time, yeah, you're probably right.

Comment: @Tomerikoo. The general idea is that you might have to know whether the line is last *before* you process it.

Comment: Yeah I get that it might be good in some cases... I was quick to dismay. Thanks for the explanations :)

Answer (score 3):

Generally you don't want to try to figure that out inside the loop, but rather, you'll know you've reached the end when the loop exits. If you want to do something special if you've reached the end (and might sometimes `break` out of the loop), you can add an `else` clause to the `for`:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    for line in file:
        if not do_stuff(line):
            break
    else: # got to the end without breaking
        do_something_special_with_last_line(line)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the fact that files are iterators, you can use the following generic recipe. It returns a status flag along with each line. The flag is `True` for the last element of the underlying iterator:

```
def is_last(iterator):
    prev = next(iterator)  # immediate StopIteration possible
    for item in iterator:
        yield False, prev
        prev = item
    yield True, prev
```

You would use it like

```
with open(...) as infile:
    for last, line in is_last(infile):
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) like this:

```
from collections import deque


def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as infile:
        dq = deque([next(infile)], 1)
        for line in infile:
            yield dq[0]
            dq.append(line)

    # Last line of file.
    yield 'LAST LINE: ' + dq[0]


corpus_file = 'corpus_file.txt'

for line in read_file(corpus_file):
    print(line, end='')
```